# Solving $z^3+3i\overline{z}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$z^3+3i\overline{z}=0$$

$z=x+yi$
$$(x+yi)^3+3i(x-yi)=0$$
$$x^3+3x^2yi-3xy^2-y^3i+3ix+3y=0$$

$$x^3-3xy^2+3y=0\text{  and  }  3x^2y-y^3+3x=0$$

How to continue from here?

Comment: It would be easier with the "polar" form: $z=re^{i\phi}$.

Comment: I'd have started with $z=re^{it}$.

Comment: I get $re^{-i\theta}(r^2e^{4i\theta}+3i)=0$

Comment: So, either $r=0$ or $r^2e^{4i\theta}=-3i$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown and so $r=\sqrt{3}$ and $\theta=\frac{3}{16}$?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $z$,

$$z^4+3i|z|^2=0$$ so that $z^4$ is purely imaginary. Then with $\omega$ a fourth root of $-i$,

$$-ir^4+3ir^2=0.$$

We have $r=0\lor r=\sqrt3$ and

$$z=0\lor z=\sqrt 3\,\omega$$ (five solutions in total).

Comment: You plugged $z=r$ and multiplied by $-i$ to get to $-ir^4+3ir^2=0$? not by $z=re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @newhere: no, I plugged $z=r\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z^3+3i\overline{z}=0\to \overline{z}^3-3iz=0$$

sum both equation

$$(z^3+\overline{z}^3)+3i(z-\overline{z})=0\to Re(z^3)+3i(iIm(z))=0$$
$$Re(z^3)=3Im(z)$$

If we call $z=re^{i\theta}$ then

$$r^3\cos(3\theta)=3r\sin\theta$$

as already said before, it is easy to get that $r=0$ or $r=\sqrt{3}$. For $r=0$ then $z=0$ and for $r=\sqrt{3}$ then:

$$\cos(3\theta)=\sin\theta\to\cos(3\theta)-\cos(\theta-\pi/2)=0$$

$$-2\sin(2\theta-\pi/4)\sin(\theta+\pi/4)=0$$

finish the calculations and find all possibles values of $\theta$.